# How can I prepopulate a terminal prompt with a command or partial command?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, command-line, command-line-interface

I would like to write a command/function that will prepopulate my terminal prompt with a partial command or text. I need to prefix my git commit messages and I was thinking it would be useful for this (and other uses) if I could prefill the prompt with a partial command rather than always needing to retype the same thing.

```
> gencommit
> git commit -m "ABC-123:
```

In the code snippet above, `git commit -m "ABC-123:`  is placed on the command line and I would simply be able to add a commit message and execute the command.

`echo` is the only thing that comes to mind but that does not do what I want, If `gencommit` used echo it would look something like this.

```
> gencommit
git commit -m "ABC-123:
>
```

Comment: Use `alias` or functions.

Comment: What should be the trigger to have the words _git commit_ magically appear in the command line? Waving a wand, pressing a hotkey, or do you only want to save typing effort and want have an abbreviation? On my plattform for instance, I use a function named `gencom` for this purpose, but I still have to type 6 characters (actually 7, due to the space needed) before I can entere the commit message. Is this still too much  for you?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `bash` doesn't provide any way to *write* to the Readline buffer programatically.  (`zsh` does, as an aside.) One alternative is to make `gencommit` a Readline macro. For example, add this to your `.inputrc` file (creating the file if necessary):

```
"gencommit": "git commit -m \"ABC-123:"
```

One thing about his approach that I find disconcerting is that because a macro is text that gets replaced immediately, Readline won't actually echo the text you are typing to the screen until it has determined what macro you are typing, so while you are typing `gencommit`, nothing appears on your screen until you finish, then the expansion text appears. Worse, if you make a mistake while typing, you have to cancel the command and start over.

Better is to define an alias

```
alias gencommit='git commit -m "ABC-123:'
```

and, after typing `gencommit` on the command line, use the `shell-expand-line` Readline function (bound to `M-!` by default; `M` is the meta key, which is either Alt or Esc, depending on your platform and terminal emulator settings) to expand it to the replacement text. (This tries to expand *anything* on the command line: aliases, parameters, history expansions, etc. There is a dedicated `alias-expand-line` function that *only* expands aliases, but it is unbound by default. I leave it as an exercise to bind this command to an unused key sequence if you like.)

---

As I alluded to `zsh`, the command in that shell would simply be

```
print -z 'git commit -m "ABC-123:'
```